# I want to set by default keyword value null and also want to set error message if record not found by keyword how it possible

Tags: angular

HTML Component:

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        name="keyword" [(ngModel)]="model.keyword" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getEmployees()">Search</button>
</form>
```

Component:
I want to set `null` as default value for `keyword`

```ts
getEmployees(page:number,keyword:string): void {
  this.employeeService.getEmployees(page,this.model.keyword)
    .subscribe(employees => { 
      this.employees = employees;
      console.log(this.employees);
      this.setPage(page);
      console.log(this.model.keyword)
    });
}
```

Comment: When do you want to call these? What is the condition for switching between these URLs? Is it, for example, when `keyword` has value, call "keyword" endpoint. When `keyword` doesn't have a value, call "page" endpoint? Or something else?

Comment: actually by default keyword value taken undefined so that error come I want to set keyword value null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 getEmployees(page:number,keyword:string): void {
        // get users from secure api end point
        var query = (this.model.keyword) ? this.model.keyword : "";
        this.employeeService.getEmployees(page,query)
            .subscribe(employees => {
                this.employees = employees;
                console.log(this.employees);
                this.setPage(page);           
            });
    }
```